# Support of AES 256 with GCM not possible in iOS?

Tags: ios, encryption, commoncrypto, aes-gcm

Currently the encryption mode supported with `AES 256 is CBC`. But I want to use `AES 256 encryption` with `GCM` mode along with `PKCS5Padding / PKCS7Padding`.

Do let me know how it can be done ?

Comment: You might also want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855741/how-to-encrypt-using-aes-gcm-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

Common Crypto does not support GCM. But there is an implementation of AES GCM in the Security.framework, and you can add your own header file to use it. However associated data (AEAD) does not work.

From [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36634956/451475) by soyer:

```
CCCryptorStatus CCCryptorGCM(
                 CCOperation     op, // kCCEncrypt, kCCDecrypt
                 CCAlgorithm     kCCAlgorithmAES,
                 const void      *key,    size_t  keyLength,
                 const void      *iv,     size_t  ivLen,
                 const void      *aData,  size_t  aDataLen, // does not work
                 const void      *dataIn, size_t  dataInLength,
                 void            *dataOut,
                 const void      *tag,    size_t *tagLength);
```

There is an implemntation [AES GCM](https://github.com/indisoluble/AesGcm) on github that seems reasonable albiet slow in comparison to Common Crypto. Use at your own risk.