# How to implement AES With GCM Mode Encryption and Decryption in iOS 10?

Tags: swift, encryption, ios10, aes-gcm

I want to use AES with GCM mode with 128,192,256 key sizes.

I have done AES Encryption with CBC Mode but,still I have no solution for GCM mode. If any one have please suggest some useful guidance

Comment: Check out https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift, I've used this library on a few occasions, most recently for encrypting sensitive information before I persist it to NSUserDefaults. I'm sure it can do what you are after!

Comment: CryptoSwift does not support GCM mode. It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 100 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented implementation of AES GCM in Common Crypto, by adding a header it can be used.

Note: it does not support associated data (AEAD).

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40248870/451475) for a header example.

There is an implemntation [AES GCM](https://github.com/indisoluble/AesGcm) on github that seems reasonable albiet slow in comparison to Common Crypto. Use at your own risk.