# Objective C / Is there a way to encrypt with AES256 GCM?

Tags: objective-c, aes-gcm

The system library seems to support only AES256 CBC. Is there a way to encrypt AES GCM using an external library? Or is there any other good way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encrypt using AES GCM on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855741/how-to-encrypt-using-aes-gcm-on-ios)

Comment: As I can see in apple's sources: https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60074/include/CommonCryptorSPI.h.auto.html there is exist private mode `kCCModeGCM` it's equal to `11`. You can try to use `CCCryptorCreateWithMode` and pass `11` there.